Nextjs14 "useForm" module not found
How can I resolve the error shown in the image? npm package is installed.
enter image description here
I want to write a controller inside  but it's not working. I've been trying to solve the error for a long time but couldn't figure it out.
That's my code:
"use client"

import{Dialog,DialogContent,DialogDescription,DialogHeader,DialogTitle}
from "@/components/ui/dialog"
import{Form,FormField}
from "@/components/ui/form"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import * as z from "zod"
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"

const formSchema = z.object({
    name : z.string().min(1,{
        message:"Server name is required."
    }),
    imageUrl: z.string().min(1,{
        message:"Server image is required"
    })
})

export const InitialModal = () => {

    const form = useForm({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues:{
            name:"",
            imageUrl:"",
        }
    })

    const isLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;

    const onSubmit = async(values:z.infer<typeof formSchema>)=>{
        console.log(values)
    }

  return (
    <Dialog open>
        <DialogContent className="bg-white text-black p-0 overflow-hidden">
            <DialogHeader className="pt-8 px-6">
                <DialogTitle className="text-2xl text-center font-bold">
                    Customize your server
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogDescription className="text-center text-zinc-500">
                    Give your server a personality with a name and an image. You can always change it later.
                </DialogDescription>
            </DialogHeader>
            <Form {...form}>
                <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                 className="space-y-8"
                >
                  <div className="space-y-8 px-6">
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-center text-center">
                        TODO: Image Upload
                    </div>
                    <FormField  />
                  </div>
                </form>
            </Form>
        </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  )
}


I think you shouldn't import from "react-hook-form/dist", but just from "react-hook-form"

When I do that, I get these errors: Cannot find module 'react-hook-form' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307). TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')

Then there is probably something wrong in your code. Could you add a reproducible example of the problem to the post?

I added my code to the question

I tried reproducing it in a next 14 project, but everything seems to work just fine. I got the same Cannot find module warning in my editor when I installed the package, but that went away after reloading the editor. I don't believe I can help you further with this.

Same issue and same resolution: restarted VS Code and import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"; works
